# How to get the Receiver Object from Blazor @onclick method

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a button, which I want to get the Reciever object in my onclick method.
ie:
[image]

Usually on my @onclick events I will do something like this:

```
 @foreach (var file in Files.OrderBy(a => a.Title))
                {
                    <tr 
                        @onclick="() => onButtonClick(file)"  
                    >...
                }
```

However in this situation, I want to know the target that was actually clicked (ie in the row, was it a checkbox or was it anything else. So I assume I need the object receiver (as seen in the snippit in image #1)
I also need the file object from the foreach loop.

So I tried to do this::

```
 @foreach (var file in Files.OrderBy(a => a.Title))
            {
                <tr 
                    class="@(file.Active ? "item-active" : "" )" 
                    @onclick="(object receiver, Action callback) => onButtonClick(recevier, file)"
                > 
             }
```

how ever that gives me the error:

*Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'EventCallback' because it is not a delegate type*

How can I get the reciever object, and my file object from Blazor Razor page?

Comment: @onclick doesn't return the sender.  It's a C# UI event derived from the JS browser event.  In your example you're trying to return a `tr` which is a html element.  What can you do with it?

Comment: I was hoping receiver meant the element that received the click... I basically want it to do one thing if row is clicked and different thing if checkbox within that row is clicked. Currently when j click checkbox the row click element fires

Comment: See my answer below.   You just need to sort out propagation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `@onclick:stopPropagation=true` to stop the click event propagating from the cell down to the row.

Here's a demo page showing it in use:

```cs
@page "/"
@using System.Text

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<table>
    <tr @onclick=this.OnClick style="cursor:pointer">
        <td class="px-5">Hello, I can be clicked</td>
        <td class="px-5"><InputCheckbox @bind-Value=this.isChecked @onclick:stopPropagation=true></InputCheckbox></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick=this.ButtonClick>Click Me</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-success" @onclick:stopPropagation=true @onclick=this.ButtonClick>Click Me</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
<pre> Checked @isChecked</pre>
<pre>@_sb.ToString()</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private StringBuilder _sb = new();
    private bool isChecked;

    private void OnClick()
        => _sb.AppendLine("row clicked");

    private void ButtonClick()
        => _sb.AppendLine("button clicked");
}
```